# In OAuth2 flow, can we delegate authentication to Windows SSO

Tags: windows, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, kerberos

We have an in-house OAuth2 server used by our applications. Now we want to use Windows SSO for our applications but without them to change anything: they'll still reach our OAuth2 server for an access token and the authentication part will be delegated to Kerberos (which Windows use, if I understood properly).

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

That is a standard setup and should just require configuration changes in the Authorization Server (AS) - with zero code changes in applications.

Most commonly:

- The AS might be hosted in the cloud
- It will redirect browsers to an on premise Identity Provider (IDP)
- The IDP can connect to Active Directory

You may also need a fallback option for when users are not joined to the work domain. See this [Curity guide](https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/authentication-service-admin-guide/authenticators/windows.html) for an example and some infrastructure factors to think about.

If the AS is in house it may even be able to make a direct Kerberos connection via an LDAP data source, though the preferred architecture is a separate IDP.

Of course you need an AS that supports the ability to make this type of connection, so would need to check the vendor docs.

**REQUEST FLOW**

Kerberos has always been the simplest protocol conceptually but the deepest to understand - here is a bit of a summary:

- Your apps will make a standard OpenID Connect authorization redirect to the AS
- The AS may then present an authentication selection screen to the user, unless there is only a single option
- Alternatively an app can send the acr_values query parameter to say which authentication method to use
- The AS will then redirect the browser to the next stage of processing, that uses a 'Windows SSO authenticator'
- The redirect to the Windows SSO authenticator does not have to use OpenID Connect - it could be any vendor specific HTTP request
- The browser will send an encrypted Kerberos ticket automatically by connecting to AD - a prerequisite for this to work might be that the domain in the URL is in the Local Intranet zone on end user computers
- The Windows SSO  authenticator will need to be able to decrypt this credential, which typically requires a Service Principal Name to be configured
- Once the Kerberos ticket is decrypted, the authenticator will make an LDAP connection to an Active Directory data source via its standard LDAP endpoints, to verify the received ticket

Comment: Hi, thank you for your insight! I'm a bit confused though, I'm new to Kerberos and NTLM, I only know OAuth2. From what I'm understanding, AS is my OAuth2 server? And it will redirect to the IDP (which I believe in the case of Windows SSO is Active Directory?) But then, how the browser is redirect back to my OAuth2 server and how do I know the request is authenticated? What is the flow of requests? Thank you very much again!

Comment: Ha - you brought back some memories of how complicated this is - the code is pretty much zero but the infra is complicated - I added some details on the request flow

Comment: Glad my question brought you back in time :D Thank you for this detailed flow! I understand more now: switching to Windows SSO mode is automatic as long as the browser is configured properly, that was one of the thing I was trying to figure out. The last thing missing from what I read, is how the browser is supposed to come back to my OAuth2 server? Thank you so much again for your detailed explanation!